# Why is the Hyndman and Fan 1996 recommendation for sample quantile definition to standardize on not more accepted?

Tags: sample, quantiles, definition

The 1996 paper *Sample quantiles in statistical packages* is often cited as the comprehensive source of sample quantile definitions and many a software package refers to the paper in the description of which sample quantile definitions are supported and which one is the default in that package.

However, the paper also has a conclusion which recommends a specific definition, definition 8, and the last paragraph of the paper shows much concern for the issue of a lack of standardization on a single sample quantile definition:

> The current variation in sample quantile definitions causes confusion, and so there is a need to standardize the definition of sample quantile across packages and within packages. This is an analogous situation to the problem of defining sample variance. In that case the statistical community has adopted the unbiased definition (with denominator *n - 1*) as the standard rather than the more intuitive average of squared deviations (with denominator *n*) or the minimum MSE definition (with denominator *n + 1* for a normal distribution). This avoids confusion and ensures comparable results on all software. We believe there is a similar need to adopt a standard sample quantile definition, and we propose that [definition 8] is the best choice.

Since it seems the paper is quite well-known and even influential, how come the proposal to standardize on definition 8 isn't more accepted?

What I mean is that I don't know of any software which has definition 8 as the default sample quantile.

This post by Hyndman actually discusses the issue somewhat: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/sample-quantiles-20-years-later/

> No major software uses type 8 by default, and the diversity of definitions continues 20 years later. In fact, the paper may have had the opposite effect to what was intended. We drew attention to the many approaches to computing sample quantiles and several software products added them all as options. Our own quantile function for R allows all 9 to be computed, and has type 7 as default (for backwards consistency – the price we had to pay to get R core to agree to include our function).

I'd still like to know how is definition 8 perceived in the community, though.

Comment: There may be no better answer than "inertia", which is precisely the backward compatibility Hyndman writes about.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect users on this forum to tell you the reasons (or lack of reasons) for non-action adopted by software programmers elsewhere.  If you would like to know why these programmers have not adopted the stipulated standard for their definitions, why not ask *them*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment: Maybe three reasons:

**(a) Inertia,** as @StephanKolassa has suggested.

**(b) Lack of interest.** For reasonably large samples there is not a big difference
between types--in particular, not between types 7 and 8.

```
set.seed(1208)
u = runif(50, 1, 100)
quantile(u)
       0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
 1.492819 28.731160 44.633864 64.503827 94.705649 
quantile(u, type=8)
       0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
 1.492819 28.324517 44.633864 64.669602 94.705649 

v = rnorm(100, 50, 10)
quantile(v)
      0%      25%      50%      75%     100% 
26.97106 42.85687 48.07270 53.12088 82.85653 
quantile(v, type=8)
      0%      25%      50%      75%     100% 
26.97106 42.63319 48.07270 53.13611 82.85653 

w = rexp(200, .01)
quantile(w)
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
  0.5400784  35.1372574  71.9218030 146.4547186 479.7174323 
 quantile(w, type=9)
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
  0.5400784  34.7783369  71.9218030 147.0219267 479.7174323
```

**(c) In order to overcome (a) and (b),** there would have to be
clear practical advantages of type 8 over type 7. Perhaps Hyndman and Fan
did not give persuasive evidence of that.

Arguably, a frequent application of sample quantiles is to estimate
population quantiles. Suppose we have a sample of size $n = 50$ from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=15).$ Let's see how well quantile types
7 and 8 perform as estimates of the upper quartile $110.1173$ of this distribution.

```
q3.pop = qnorm(.75, 100, 15)
[1] 110.1173
```

For type 7 (default in R):

```
set.seed(2020)
q3.7 = replicate(10^5, quantile(rnorm(50,100,15), .75))
mean(q3.7); sd(q3.7)
[1] 109.8367
[1] 2.834326
sqrt( mean( (q3.7-q3.pop)^2 ) )
[1] 2.848175
```

For type 8 (recommended by H&F):

```
set.seed(2020)
q3.8 = replicate(10^5, quantile(rnorm(50,100,15), .75, type=8))
mean(q3.8); sd(q3.8)
[1] 110.1456
[1] 2.862952
sqrt( mean( (q3.8-q3.pop)^2 ) )
[1] 2.863078
```

For 100,000 samples of fifty, we can anticipate about two-place accuracy.
In summary: types 7 and 8 may have small and about equal biases is opposite directions. Type 7 may have a smaller variance and a smaller root mean square error. (I would show histograms for the simulated upper quartiles for comparison, but they are *very* nearly identical.) Just based on this, I would hardly be motivated to overcome inertia and campaign for R to change its default from type 7 to 8, much less for universal acceptance
of type 8.

Maybe a steadfast advocate of type 8 has a compelling example of its superiority.

Comment: The speculative nature of this answer just reinforces the silliness of the question --- users on this forum cannot reasonably be expected to explain the internal mental processes of outside programmers.

Comment: However, if the methods of finding quantiles gave remarkably different results, it would be worthwhile exploring which method is best for which purposes. One is entitled to _hope_ programmers of statistical software would care about that. // Also, the Question and its links give some insight into the deliberations about the implementation in R. // That is not to say I expect anyone to take my brief exploration too seriously.